# Single Sign on from Multipe Domains

Tags: .net, forms, authentication

I have one domain such as http://www.mydomain.com and I have multple domains pointing to the same location in IIS by defining host headers, such as http://www.myONEdomain.com, http://www.myTWODomain.com, etc.

In the code I use Request.Url.Host to determine which url the user came from and then I act differently in each page based on the domain.

HOWEVER, if the user logs in at www.mydomain.com, they also need access to myONEdomain, myTWOdomain, etc.

**Does anyone know how I can acheive this in .net authentication?**

Obvisously, the login from the first domain works correctly, but as soon as the user clicks on a link that redirects them to a different domain, there is some functions that they are unable to do because the **IsAuthenticated** method returns false.

I hope I explained the situation well and that it makes sense, if not please ask.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Ironically I came across a rather extensive document of this just yesterday.  I personally use a behind the scene API to pass a session from the main login gateway to sister sites, but this explains the process in great detail:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CrossDomainSSOExample.aspx

Comment: Very interesting article... but I think my case may be slightly different.  I have multiple domains, but they all point to the same directory in IIS.  Essentially it is all one domain... in my search I came across this: http://forums.asp.net/p/1023838/1390821.aspx Seems like I should be able to append the cookie with my additional sites.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Issue is even though it is in the same IIS directory, a cookie is stored by your browser based on domain.  Example: You can not set a cookie for www.AOL.com from your site www.blah.com, so when you go from www.blah.com, www.AOL.com has no way to access the cookies from www.Blah.com and vise versa.

Comment: This is how I do it...  i have 1 main gateway, lets call it Server A, then 4 sites, B, C, D.  When you go to Site B, i check the membership class to see if the user is logged in. If so, continue, if not, redirect to server A, attaching an ID to the site (www.servera.com/?redirect=www.siteb.com).  Server A has the login form.. On login, if successful, server A generates a session ID and stores to a DB or in memory. It sets a cookie to the user storing them as logged in on ServerA. It then redirects to the query site (www.siteb.com) appending ?key=%SESSION%.

Comment: now that we are on SiteB.com, we still see we are not logged in locally, but we do see that the query string 'key' has a session now.  In this step, SiteB.com connects to a page on ServerA, passing the key.  Server A checks the db to make sure key exists. If so, send back success (or whatever u want... maybe username), if not, send back failed.  At this point you either send them to a session expired, reloggin page if failed, or you mark them in the Membership class as now "Online" and continue.

Comment: Now assume you go to SiteC.com after already online for SiteB.com.  SiteC.com is not yet logged in so it sends them to ServerA.com, which see's based on cookies "Hey this guy is already logged in, don't so the login form. Lets just create a new session just like before and auto redirect to SiteC.com with the new session.

Comment: It's a bit confusing to explain here but thats the over all jist.  You have 1 main gateway that does the login, then just create a API in coding that verifies with this gateway if they are connected.  Each site you go to will have to verify with this gateway once in order to verify there online. This works if there in the same directory on IIS, or totally different servers.  Each will need to store it's own cookie since thats how browser works, so each need to go through the process

Comment: Yes, understood, and your approach will work for me, I have thought of that and I will most likely go that route for lack of anything better, HOWEVER, i have read alot about using the same machinekey and sharing the cookie cross domains, even som MS article say it can be done across apps, but it does not work for me. One sample has domain1.com and domain2.com and they claim it works. Since I am at a loss for anything better and your comments were along the lines of what i was going to do, i will accept the answer. But, I would still love to hear more about machineKey and cross domain!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to my mind is to [make a cross-domain cookie](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/971108.htm).