# sites integration

Tags: c#, asp.net

hey anyone had this task before ? suppose you have a website called www.a.com and a second www.b.com

the the a.com have a button. when you logged in to a.com and click the button you will be send to b.com the question is how can i do this while keeping the credentials of the user when he is sent to b.com i want him automatically logged in to b.com ...PS: every user has an account in a.com he definitely should have an account in b.com .... any ideas please???.... thank u for you ideas and supports :)

Comment: what is the authentication method you are using? Forms?

Comment: this is called single-sign-on(sso), google may help you

Answer (score 0):

Single Sign On is the term you are looking for: one login should authenticate the user into all site in the group.
This is surprisingly not easy to achieve, if you have different SLD-s (second level domains).

Easiest way is to have a 3rd party to authenticate for you like Facebook, google or Twitter (thus using OAuth2). Other solutions can be crafter in a matter of hours but in general: it request that www.a.com and www.b.com communicates in the background.

Check this, it has an answer that looks promising: [Single Sign on from Multipe Domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917912/single-sign-on-from-multipe-domains)

Comment: a and b are two different websites with two different database and two different domains can i achiever SSO in a situation like this ?

Comment: yes, definitely. with some sort of shared state: either a service or a database...

Answer (score 0):

you should use session authentication in both websites, then pass the data in sessions from a.com to b.com, in b.com you will have the ability to access the data.

another solution will be that both websites access the same database and use flags in table users for example to check if this user is logged in so keep him logged in from the other website (b.com).

P.S. Don't use querystrings no matter how encrypted they are.

Comment: by using SQL Server Session State Provider http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478952.aspx

Answer (score -2):

encrypted querystring might be the solution

Comment: If you added some hashing and a time-based expiry it shouldn't be insecure. This is how http://login.live.com does it.